# Build jar for each main class using gradle

Tags: gradle

1. 1.My project has two main class i want to build jar for each main class using gradle. my source has 2 files   ValidationRule.java 
        SupportValidator.java both the file have one main class each i want to
        build the jar for each main class
        i can achieve the same from eclipse working fine
        2.I want to load the source file for my project from 2 different folder,some part is there in one folder and remaining is
   there in
        another folder i.e like
        project/src snd another folder outside the project(../../../SharedClass)

   my script as follows

   ```
   apply plugin: 'eclipse'
   apply plugin: 'java'

   sourceCompatibility = 1.6
   archivesBaseName = 'Process_XY'

   configurations {
       configurations.compile.transitive = false
   }

   dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir:'/trunk/Solutions/project/Source/Binaries/CommonFunctions/build/libs', include: '*.jar')
       compile fileTree(dir:'/trunk/Solutions/project/lib/GeoTools/geotools-2.7.4-bin/geotools-2.7.4', include: '*.jar')
       compile "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:1.0.3"
       compile "commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1"
       compile "commons-configuration:commons-configuration:1.6"
       compile "commons-discovery:commons-discovery:0.2"
       compile "commons-lang:commons-lang:2.4"
       compile "commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1"
       compile "commons-logging:commons-logging:1.0.4"
       compile "log4j:log4j:1.2.16"
       compile "com.vividsolutions:jts:1.8"
       compile "commons-net:commons-net:1.4.1"
       compile "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:1.0.3"
       compile "commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.0.1"
       compile "org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api:2.5-20081211"
       compile "org.apache.hbase:hbase:0.94.0"
       compile "org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:3.4.3"
   }

   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
       maven { url "https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/" }
       maven { url "http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release" }
       maven { url "http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone" }
       maven { url "http://repo.springsource.org/libs-snapshot" }
       maven { url "http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2/" }
       maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
       maven { url "http://people.apache.org/~rawson/repo" }
   }

   jar {
       from configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
       manifest.attributes("Main-Class":"org.project.seismic.Process_XY")
   }   

   sourceSets {
       main {
           java {
                source = ['src/org', '../../../SharedClass/org']
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   above in sourceSets method i tried to load source from 2 folder but it
    didnt worked

   Thanks in advance..!!
        How to achieve using gradle.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit what you're asking? What is the directory structure you're looking at? What have you tried?

Answer (score 7):

Ok, first of all, the `source` on a `SourceDirectorySet` takes another `SourceDirectorySet`. The `srcDirs` method however takes paths. Change that block to the following:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDirs ['src/org', '../../../SharedClass/org']
    }
  }
}
```

And you can easily add a second jar task as follows:

```
task secondJar(type: Jar) {
  name = other-main-jar
  from ...
  manifest.attributes(...)
}

assemble.dependsOn(secondJar)
```

This will register a new Jar task called `secondJar` and makes sure that when the project is assembled, this jar is also created.

Comment: can u give more clarification regarding this

Comment: Not entirely clear what you don't understand from my answer. What are you missing, or how did I not answer your questions?